# mysqldump: Couldn't find table: somenumber.sql ex 13:45:08.sql

Tags: mysql

i am trying to backup my database using mysqldump

code

```
exec('D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin\mysqldump -h'.$HOSTNAME.' -u'.$DBUSER.' -p'.$DBPASS.' dbname -t tablename > '.$mysqlExportPath.' --log-error="DumpError.txt');
```

and i got following output

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.17, for Win32 (x86)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: database name
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.17

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Dump Error

mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "13:44:43.sql"

1.problem is mysqldump not writing table structure and data in output.
2.table name is display as 13:44:43.sql where as my table name is like abc.
3.if i run same code with same tablename again table name in dump error changes with other numeric ex. next time it is 13:45:08.sql.

plz help i am not able to find that numeric table name problem any ware.

solved.
date(); have space between date and time so time was taken as table name due to space.

Comment: Do you execute this within Java ?

Comment: I have the same problem :/